# Excel: Count rows that contain a number from a random starting point

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I write:

```
=COUNTA(20:20)
```

I get the amount of cells that contain a number in row 20. Is it possible to start from cell C20 and count the numbers from there on?
If I write `=COUNTA(C20:20)` I get an error. How can I fix that?

Comment: Technicality but `COUNTA` also count text. Just `COUNT` does count cells containing numbers. Also, why not just subtract the count of `A20:B20`? Or even just `COUNT(C20:XFD20)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference one cell (`C20`) but not reference another as you did with the `20`. By referencing two cells, the formula knows how far to go. You can change `2000` to whatever number you want.

```
=COUNTA(C20:C2000)
```